# Show that the function $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{2Z}$ by $f(a)=a^3+3a+2$ is not onto

Tags: functions, relations

If the function $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{2Z}$ by $f(a)=a^3+3a+2$, then show that $f$ is not onto.

Hint: Show that $f(a)\neq 0$. I have a feeling I have to use the root theorem test, but I don't know how to go about this problem.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following you, wouldn't the possible roots beLong to the set $\{\pm 1, \pm2 \}$.  ?

Comment: For the question of being onto what  the roots of this polynomial are not directly relevant. The polynomial's drastic growth means it leaps and misses many values in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f$ is not onto, you have to show that there exists some element $x \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a) \neq x$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, let $x = 0$ and suppose there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a) = 0$. Then $a^3 + 3a + 2 = 0$. It's easy to see that $f$ is a strictly increasing function. Since our domain is the integers, let's just try a few values of a:

$$ f(-1) = -2$$
$$ f(0) = 2$$

Since $f$ is strictly increasing, any zero of $f$ would have to be in the interval $(-1, 0)$. However, there are no integers in this interval. Therefore there does not exist an integer $a$ such that $f(a) = 0$. Hence, $f$ is not onto.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an algebra problem about roots.
Calculate the difference in the value of $f$ at consecutive positive integers: $$f(a+1)-f(a) = (a+1)^3-a^3 +3(a+1-a) = 3a^2 +3a+4 \ge10.$$ This shows the function is increasing and jumps by a quantity of 10 or more. Obviously it cannot cover all even integers. So this function not onlly misses 0 in its image, it misses infinitely many even integers too.  (It is possible to interpret this answer as a discretised version of Danny's answer, as divided difference is discrete derivative. But we are able to show more missing numbers in the image).